# Why is my French drain not working?

Tags: drainage

I recently dug a French drain on one side of my house. It starts at 18 inches deep, with a catch basin on highest end. It slopes down to the front of my house. I used perforated corrugated pipe, with ten feet of solid pipe at the end, number 2 river rock as the aggregate, and wrapped it in super geotextile brand fabric. Yesterday, I tried to test it by turning my hose on and letting it drain on to the adjacent patio for 10 minutes if not longer. I was shocked to find water still making its way into my basement, and what’s more, I could see water flowing from under the French drain, down slope towards the front of the house, but the water didn’t make it inside the solid attached to the end of the French drain. I was shocked to see no difference at all. What could be the cause for a brand new French drain not doing its job? Or am I just testing this the wrong way?

Thanks

Here’s a diagram [image]

Comment: Can you add a diagram that shows the slope that you have measured?